# How to create a scope?

Tags: unity, application-development, unity-dash, scopes

I'd like to create a custom scope that searches and returns results from an online source for personal use.

Is this possible? And if so, how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it is absolutely possible and really easy to create new scopes. The Ubuntu App Developer site has lots of content to get you started writing scopes:

- [Scopes overview](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/scopes/)
- [Tutorial: Writing a scope](http://developer.ubuntu.com/scopes/tutorial/)
- [Scopes cookbook](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/scopes/cookbook/)

Answer (score 10):

For development in python:

**Update for 12.04:**

Unity lens development with singlet has been integrated into quickly:

```
quickly create unity-lens <lens-name>
```

**For 11.10:**

You might want to look at a very nice wrapper class developed by [Michael Hall called singlet](http://mhall119.com/2012/01/simplified-unity-lens-development-with-singlet/): https://launchpad.net/singlet

A simple hello world lens would look like this:

```
#! /usr/bin/python
from singlet.lens import SingleScopeLens, IconViewCategory
from singlet.utils import run_lens

class HelloWorldLens(SingleScopeLens):
    class Meta:
        name = 'helloworld'

    cat1 = IconViewCategory("Cat One", "stock_yet")

    def search(self, phrase, results):
        results.append('http://google.com/search?q=%s' % phrase,
                             'file',
                             self.cat1,
                             "text/html",
                             phrase, phrase, '')
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    run_lens(HelloLens, sys.argv)
```

Which is a lot simpler and faster to write than the original library versions.

Answer (score 2):

The [Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Unity/Lenses) has a tutorial on how to write a Lens that uses Vala. Saravanan Thirumuruganathan wrote [one for Python](http://saravananthirumuruganathan.wordpress.com/2011/08/05/tutorial-on-writing-ubuntu-lensesplaces-in-python/). The [Unity Sample Place](https://launchpad.net/unity-lens-sample)  has some simple example lenses written in python and Vala.

As far as I know it's not (yet?) possible to write lenses in PHP.

Comment: There are GObject bindings for PHP (https://github.com/indeyets/gobject-for-php), so it should be possible, although learning python might be easier than making them work.

Comment: Please note that the linked python tutorial uses old API, the one on Ubuntu wiki is up-to-date.

Answer (score 1):

There are a bunch of tutorials in the Ubuntu Lens wiki.  The easiest I think is one I found on a [blog here](http://mhall119.com/2012/01/simplified-unity-lens-development-with-singlet/).

[Here is the wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Unity/Lenses).

Comment: These are basically the links given in the question. How is this helping?

Comment: the blog link is not in the question