# Is their any way pinning location to unity dash?

Tags: 16.04, launcher, unity-dash, .desktop

i wanna add location or application to the main screen of unity dash instead of making a lot of `.desktop` files and pin to launcher
[image] 
on windows i simply pin location to start like this .
[image]
is their any way to do this on ubuntu ?

Comment: Wait, I misread your question. I am pretty sure however here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/524576/how-can-i-add-folder-shortcuts-to-the-unity-launcher you'll find a solution to the directory part.

Comment: Adding it to *Dash* is the same as creating extra `.desktop` files. Dash is populated with `.desktop` files. You should not create multiple desktop files, calling the same application in their main command. Ubuntu has different solutions to reach multiple directory without overpopulating the Unity Launcher, mentioned in the link. In that sense, the link answers your question.

Comment: this not solve the problem  i can search automatically on dash and it will get the folder or app instead of making it

Comment: Apps *are* in Dash, unless you installed them locally without a .desktop file, no need to make them, and you can search them.

Comment: after searching the solution is to create my custom scope :\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately their's no direct solution try to create your custom ***scope*** here is a question for [how to create scope](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91065/how-to-create-a-scope)  and [here](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/phone/scopes/tutorials/write-a-xml-scope-in-cpp/) a link for how to create on `unity 8`